# Get data from select statement mysql.connector

Tags: python, sql, mysql-connector

How do I store the content a select statement into a variable?

I have a table called testing with 2 fields: ID, and events.

I do `SELECT * FROM testing WHERE id=1;` to get the row, but how do I get the data in the events column of that row and store it into a variable `x`? I couldn't find how to do this online.

Comment: `x = testing%rowtype` ? what does this do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to do this in python and I suppose you have already connected your database and put it in a variable named `conn`

```
sql = "select * from Laptop"
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
x = cursor.fetchall()
```

and your result will be stored in the `x` variable

Comment: will x["events"] return the data in the events column of the returned result?

Comment: @mistertwst x has an array of tuples and if you want to get a specific row you'll need to get it by index . 
this is an example of the x varialbe for a table that has 3 columns : 
`x = [  (1,'LENOVO' , 30000) , (2,'HP', 45 000)  ]`

Comment: so if I want to get 'LENOVO' I would do `y = x[0][1]`?

Comment: @mistertwst yes

Comment: Thanks for the help!